How do you configure an Azure action group at the subscription level?
I am trying to set a new budget for the subscription but it appears that any action group I create for budget alerts can only scoped at the resource group level.
Is it possible to create an action group for the entire subscription? Seems odd that a budget can be scoped to the subscription level, but the action groups (apparently) cannot.
Is this something than can only be done via the PS console?


I think you misunderstood the term here. Action Group is a resource entity of Azure Monitor. It has to belong to a resource group. However, it does not mean that it only functions within that resource group scope. You should be able to set up alerts across resources in the subscription.


How do you configure an Azure action group at the subscription level?

It is not possible to configure an action group directly at subscription level because action group is a resource which can be deployed under a specific resource group.
After a workaround on your requirement, I found below approach to add alerts at a subscription scope.
Go to your Subscription >> Budgets under cost Management section. There click on Add as shown below.

It redirects you to the below page to create a budget alert.

Once it's done, you can set up alert condition, an alert recipient's mail addresses and also add an action group to monitor the subscription costs and alerts as per your requirement.

Using Azure CLI or PowerShell console, when creating action groups, they are scoped to a specific resource group. This means that you can only create an action group within the context of a specific resource group.
az monitor action-group create --name 'newactjah' --resource-group xxx


Reference:
Set-AzActionGroup using PowerShell
Also check MSDoc for the relevant information on automating alerts and action groups.
